# Java Decoding name in Content-Type: application/pdf;

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, base64, decoding

I'm trying to read the **eml** file and save the attachments using a Java and Tomcat 9.
But I have a problem when I manage this content type:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="=?utf-8?Q?Men=C3=B9_Miki_travel=2Epdf?="
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename="=?utf-8?Q?Men=C3=B9_Miki_travel=2Epdf?="
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

If I try to print the content type I have this output, **what is this format?**:

```
application/pdf; name="=?utf-8?Q?Men=C3=B9_Miki_travel=2Epdf?="
```

Why in content type is there the name?
How can I manage It and convert the name in the real name (Menu' My Restaurant.pdf) managing the spaces and special caracters?

```
        MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) message.getContent();
        emlBody = getTextFromMimeMultipart(mimeMultipart);  

        Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();

        int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();

        for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {

            MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);

            if(part.getFileName()!=null) {
                //define variable
                String strAttachment = "";
                String myFileName = part.getFileName();

                if (part.getContentType().toLowerCase().contains("application/pdf; name=")) {
                    System.out.println("Conentype: " + part.getContentType());
                    myFileName = "attach"+ partCount + ".pdf";
                } 

                //define variable
                String myPathSave = mypath + myFileName;
                String myPathHref = mypathHref + myFileName;

                try {

                    if (partCount==1) {
                        strAttachment = "<B>Attachment:</B>";
                    } else {
                        strAttachment = "";
                    }

                    part.saveFile(myPathSave);

                } catch (IOException exc) {
                    System.out.println(exc.toString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried URL decoding?

Comment: Yes, I have. Could you write an example, please?